# How to define latest and stable node image version in yaml file of pipeline without writing version number manually

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have circled the version in attached picture so that This version to be dynamic which is latest and stable

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use " image: node:lts " and it will use most latest LTS (LONG-TERM SUPPORTED) node image

this is for bitbucket pipeline